# How to hide CMFCToolBar from customize dialog Toolbar property page?

Tags: c++, mfc, toolbar, cmfctoolbar, cmfcpropertypage

I am working on Mfc application that contains ribbon and some toolbars. I made a CMFCToolBar dummy object to store all the icons from ribbon tabs and use it later.

I have hidden the dummy toolbar from the UI. but couldn't hide from customize dialog Toolbar Property Page. 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fdtfd.png)(untitled bar is the dummy toolbar)

I dont want the user to see the dummy toolbar in the property page. For this I have also made CMFCToolBarsCustomizeDialog extension and inherited the ShowToolBar Function but it is not working.

Code:

```
void ShowToolBar(CMFCToolBar* pToolBar, BOOL bShow)
    {
        this->m_pToolbarsPage->ShowToolBar(pToolBar, bShow);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply override `CMFCToolBar::AllowShowOnList` and return FALSE.

```
BOOL CMyToolBar::AllowShowOnList() const 
{ 
  return FALSE;
}
```